# Glimpse hanging website, calling validation code for nor fathomable reason

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-3, glimpse

I've got a fairly large ASP.NET MVC site, migrated from 1 to 2, and now on MVC 3.0. I added Glimpse to it and it hangs.

In the stack trace, there's a call to Glimpse.Core.DLL!Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DynamicValueProvider.GetValue(target={})

It then tries to validate the model - which fails since the model isn't initialized, and shouldn't be being validated,

Anyone else come across any LINQ/Glimplse issues?

Comment: Can you share the full stack trace? Also, is your view model an EF managed object with lazy loading?

Comment: WebRefocus.DLL!MyNamespace.Models.MyModel.IsValid.get() Line 398 C#
[Lightweight Function] 
Glimpse.Core.DLL!Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DynamicValueProvider.GetValue(object target = {MyNamespace.Models.MyModel}) + 0x57 bytes 
Glimpse.Core.DLL!Glimpse.Core.Plumbing.GlimpseValueProvider.GetValue(object target) + 0x27 bytes

Answer (score 0):

Your ViewModel has an IsValid property on it that Glimpse tries to serialize for the Views tab.

You can simply disable the views tab by adding the following to your web.config:

```
<glimpse>
<pluginBlacklist>
<add plugin="Glimpse.Mvc3.Plugin.Views" />
</pluginBlacklist>
</glimpse>
```

We are looking to change the default behavior for View Model serialization in the future, but this work around should get you up and running for now.

**UPDATE:** As of [version 1.0](https://nuget.org/packages/Glimpse/), Glimpse no longer serializes View Models - which means this is no longer a problem.